# Ant Design table example code gives warning(next.js+ typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, antd

package.json

```
    "antd": "^5.0.7",
    "next": "13.0.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.4"
```

https://ant.design/components/table#using-in-typescript

```
import { Table } from 'antd';
import type { ColumnsType } from 'antd/es/table';

interface User {
  key: number;
  name: string;
}

const columns: ColumnsType<User> = [
  {
    key: 'name',
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
  },
];

const data: User[] = [
  {
    key: 0,
    name: 'Jack',
  },
];

export default () => (
  <>
    <Table<User> columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
    /* JSX style usage */
    <Table<User> dataSource={data}>
      <Table.Column<User> key="name" title="Name" dataIndex="name" />
    </Table>
  </>
);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJVXQ.png)

```
<Table<User> columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
```

`Type User[] is not assignable to type RcTableProps<RecordType>["data"] | undefined`

Why am I getting this warning?

The type of data can be known from the generics of the Table tag
dataSource arguments are arrays of the same type so no warning should be given

Comment: Please share code instead of image

Comment: @Johan Thank you for your reply
Am I missing some code?
The code that raises the warning is in this post

Comment: Can you try this : `<Table<User> columns={columns} dataSource={data as RcTableProps<RecordType>["data"]} />
`

Comment: i get cannot find RecordType